# Logging data while debugging in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Been trying to find any feature like this or a way of doing this. Basically, a way to log data through the VS debugger, instead of writing the data logging through code, as it would be much faster this way for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint at critical sections of your code, or on specific variables, and set the breakpoint to log data (instead of, or when stopping execution).

There is some basic explanation here: [using breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx). Just looking through the properties of a breakpoint will help you discover what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a great feature called [Tracepoints](http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2015/08/04/tracepoints-conditional-breakpoints-and-function-breakpoints/) - basically, a tracepoint is just like a Breakpoint, except instead of breaking into the debugger, the debugger writes a logging message to the Output window.

The great thing about Tracepoints is that you can change your logging dynamically as you debug your code - without having to your solution and re-run the program all over again each time you want to change it.

I co-created a commercial Visual Studio extension called OzCode which extends Visual Studio's Tracepoints by baking a fully featured log-viewer into Visual Studio to view the results, and allowing you to export the results to Excel. See instructional video [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vuMi-3jGwY)